# How to run local contracts with Spring Cloud Contract stub runner

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I have defined some Spring Cloud Contracts that I have packaged into a jar using `gradle verifierStubsJar`. I would like to run the stubs in that jar with the [Spring Cloud Contract stub runner jar](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-boot/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar). I do not want to have to publish the stubs jar to an artifact repository like Artifactory or a local Maven repository. I just want to run the stubs. How do I pass the location of the jar containing my stubs to the stub runner jar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `gradle generateClientStubs`:

```
curl -Lo stub-runner.jar https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-boot/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar

java -Djava.security-egd=/dev/./urandom -Dstubrunner.repositoryRoot=stubs://file://absolute/path/to/build/stubs -Dstubrunner.ids=com.company-contract:stubs:8081 -Dstubrunner.stubs-mode=REMOTE -jar stub-runner.jar
```

If you use `gradle verifierStubsJar`:

```
curl -Lo stub-runner.jar https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-boot/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar

java -cp stub-runner.jar:build/libs/my-contract-stubs.jar -Djava.security-egd=/dev/./urandom -Dstubrunner.ids=com.company:my-contract:stubs:8081 -Dstubrunner.stubs-mode=CLASSPATH org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

Gotchas:

- When using `gradle generateClientStubs` don't forget the leading slash in the absolute URI to your stubs directory. e.g. `stubs://file:///User/me/my-contracts-project/build/stubs`.
- The stub runner starts a server on port 8080, so you must run your stubs on a different port. You can override the port the stub runner starts on with the usual `-Dserver.port`.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the docs you would find this section https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/project-features.html#features-stub-runner-stubs-protocol

> Instead of picking the stubs or contract definitions from Artifactory / Nexus or Git, one can just want to point to a location on drive or classpath. This can be especially useful in a multimodule project, where one module wants to reuse stubs or contracts from another module without the need to actually install those in a local maven repository ot commit those changes to Git.
>
> In order to achieve this it’s enough to use the stubs:// protocol when the repository root parameter is set either in Stub Runner or in a Spring Cloud Contract plugin.
>
> In this example the producer project has been successfully built and stubs were generated under the target/stubs folder. As a consumer one can setup the Stub Runner to pick the stubs from that location using the stubs:// protocol.
>
> @AutoConfigureStubRunner(
>   stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.REMOTE,
>           repositoryRoot = "stubs://file://location/to/the/producer/target/stubs/",
>           ids = "com.example:some-producer")
>
> Contracts and stubs may be stored in a location, where each producer has its own, dedicated folder for contracts and stub mappings. Under that folder each consumer can have its own setup. To make Stub Runner find the dedicated folder from the provided ids one can pass a property stubs.find-producer=true or a system property stubrunner.stubs.find-producer=true .
>
> @AutoConfigureStubRunner(
>   stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.REMOTE,
>           repositoryRoot = "stubs://file://location/to/the/contracts/directory",
>           ids = "com.example:some-producer",
>           properties="stubs.find-producer=true")

Comment: How do I do this with the stub runner jar? My contracts sit in their own location separate from both the consumer and the producer. I am not using JUnit to run the stubs in this case. I am trying do something like: `java -Dstubrunner.ids=com.myname:my-contracts:8080:stubs -Dstubrunner.stubs-mode=CLASSPATH -jar stub-runner.jar`. The problem here is the jar that contains my stubs isn't actually on the classpath. And the `-cp` flag doesn't work with `-jar`.

Comment: Please read this section of the docs https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/project-features.html#features-stub-runner-boot

Comment: I am trying to do something similar to the **Using Spring Cloud Contract Stubs on the Consumer Side** section of [this tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2018/02/13/spring-cloud-contract-in-a-polyglot-world). But instead of sourcing the stubs from Artifactory , I want to source them from a local jar.

Comment: Please read the documentation. You can reuse the properties from annotations as your fat jar setup

Comment: I've been reading the documentation all morning. I haven't yet found a property that does what I want. `stubrunner.repositoryRoot` isn't applicable because I don't have a remote Maven repository. I can't set `stubrunner.stubsMode` to LOCAL because I'm using Gradle, not Maven, and so I don't have a local Maven repo. I'm looking for something like `stubrunner.stubsJar=/usr/src/stubs.jar`.

Comment: I've given you example of a working test annotation. That annotation maps exactly to the properties you need to set. You do need to provide the repository root, in the docs we describe it including the aforementioned example. You do have either local or remote case with files. Btw You can have a local maven repo when using gradle. Where did you read that you must be using local when you're using maven?

Comment: "stubrunner.repositoryRoot isn't applicable because I don't have a remote Maven repository" - `stubrunner.repositoryRoot` does not always refer to maven but also to local file system, e.g. `@AutoConfigureStubRunner(stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.REMOTE, repositoryRoot = "stubs://file://location/to/the/producer/target/stubs/", ids = "com.example:some-producer")` from docs

Answer (score 0):

After a ton of searching and struggling, this is working for me.

Add this to the producer side `build.gradle`:

```
configurations {
    // create a configuration that other modules can use
    contractStubs {
        canBeResolved = false
        canBeConsumed = true
    }
}

artifacts {
    // link the stub jar to the configuration
    contractStubs(verifierStubsJar)
}
```

Add this to the consumer side `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation project(path: ':some-path:probucer-dir', configuration: 'contractStubs')
}
```

For more info see:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cross_project_publications.html